# Why do I have to retained a strong reference to the tableView datasource?

Tags: ios, swift

I notice when I manually set the tableview datasource, I have to retain a strong reference to it, otherwise, the `cellForRowAt` wouldn't get called. (noted that the `numberOfRowsInSection` and `numberOfSections` get called)

```
class YAExploreViewController: UIViewController {
      ...
      dataSourceSubject
               .subscribe(onNext: { dataSource in
                            // I'm not storing a strong reference to the dataSource, and cellForRowAt wouldn't get called
                            self.tableView.dataSource = dataSource
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                        })
               .disposed(by: self.bag)
      ...
}
```

**Solution:**

```
class YAExploreViewController: UIViewController {
      var exploreDataSource: YAExploreDataSource?

      ...
      dataSourceSubject
               .subscribe(onNext: { dataSource in
                            // I'm storing a strong reference to the dataSource, and cellForRowAt got called
                            self.dataSource = dataSource
                            self.tableView.dataSource = self.dataSource
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                        })
               .disposed(by: self.bag)
      ...
}
```

I noticed there is a description on the tableView dataSource property:

> The object that acts as the data source of the table view. The data
>   source must adopt the UITableViewDataSource protocol. The data source
>   is not retained.

I wonder whether this is related.

Thanks

Comment: Yep, the ```dataSource``` in your first example is scoped inside the ```onNext``` block, when the block is done, the class is deallocated, since is not retained by anybody. In the second example is not the case anymore. The controller has a strong reference to it. Also, you should use ```week self``` inside the ```onNext``` block so you avoid retain cycle for your controller.

Answer (score 0):

In the table view, the `dataSource` property follow the "delegate pattern" (widely used in UIKit), which means it must be `weak` and you must retain it yourself.

The main reason is that if the table view had a strong reference to the `dataSource`, it could create a reference cycle and a memory leak in many cases (for example, if your view controller is the data source)

```
class MyController: UIViewController {
  @IBOutlet var tableview: UITableView?

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableview?.dataSource = self
  }
}

extension MyController: UITableViewDataSource {
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 0
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    return UITableViewCell(frame: .zero)
  }
}
```

If the `dataSource` were a `strong` reference, this would cause a memory leak.

If you want to know more about how the memory is managed in Swift, take a look a the [Automatic Reference Counting](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html) documentation.